# Logout in Apache Shiro

Tags: security, jsp, shiro

Am trying to add a logout functionality in Shiro, I've add this in the JSP page:

```
<a href="/logout">Log Out</a>
```

and the shiro.ini look like this:

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp
logout.redirectUrl = /logout.jsp

#[users]  
#admin = p  
#mike = p, reader
#joe = p, writer 

[urls]  
/login.jsp = authc
/logout.jsp = logout
/writer/** = user, roles[writer]
/success/** = user
#/** = anon
```

but when I try to logout, it give me a

> HTTP Status 404
>   ...
>   The requested resource () is not available.

Answer (score 5):

If you reread the documentation they suggest to have

```
[urls]
/logout = logout
```

As is it looks like you have a redirect loop going: go to logout.jsp, invoke the logout filter, redirect to logout.jsp, invoke the logout filter, etc.

So far I've been able to get it to redirect properly using this method.